# Defining an object which is function in some variables and tensor in some other indices

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I am trying to define an object which function in some variable and tensor in other indices. 
My attempt at it was:

```
Clear[mat, k];
mat[k_] := {{0,0},{0,0}};
mat[k_][[1, 1]] := k + 1
mat[k_][[1, 2]] := k + 2
mat[k_][[2, 1]] := k + 3
mat[k_][[2, 2]] := k + 4
mat[1]
```

The ouput it gives is:

```
During evaluation of In[268]:= SetDelayed::setps: mat[k_] in the part    assignment is not a symbol. >>

Out[270]= $Failed

During evaluation of In[268]:= SetDelayed::setps: mat[k_] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Out[271]= $Failed

During evaluation of In[268]:= SetDelayed::setps: mat[k_] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Out[272]= $Failed

During evaluation of In[268]:= SetDelayed::setps: mat[k_] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
Out[273]= $Failed

Out[274]= {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Could someone please points me out as to what's going wrong here and what are the ways to get what i want?

Comment: you could try to use `mat[k_][1,1]:= k + 1` instead of `mat[k_][[1,1]]:=...` , and so on.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, it doesn't work.

Comment: why not? what happened? did you get an error message? (if you did, post it here). Anyway, im not really sure about what you are trying to do in your code, but the obvious solution is to define `mat` through `mat[k_]:={{k+1,k+2},{k+3,k+4}}`, and delete the other lines of code (delete `mat[k_][[1,1]]:=...` and so on). Does this solve your issues?